# Weyl's law for hyperbolic operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth, bounded domain and consider the operator $T: L^2([0,1]\times\Omega) \to L^2([0,1]\times\Omega)$ so that $Tf = v$ if
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}v - \Delta v = f \qquad & (t,x) \in (0,1) \times\Omega;\\
v = 0 \qquad & (t,x) \in (0,1)\times\partial \Omega;\\
v(0,x) = 0 \qquad & x \in \Omega.
\end{cases}
$$
One can then consider the eigenvalues of the positive operator $T^* T$, a hyperbolic operator which is the inverse of $-\frac{d^2}{dt^2} + \Delta^2$ with appropriate boundary and initial conditions. Is there anything known about the asymptotic decay of these eigenvalues?

For the Laplace operator there is extensive literature concerning the decay (Weyl's law), are there similar results for such operators?

Comment: Why do you speak of a *hyperbolic* operator ? The order in space still differs from that in time.

Comment: @Denis Serre Perhaps hyperbolic evolution operator is a more precise term, this is wording used in _Non-Homogeneous Boundary Value Problems and Applications, Vol II_, Lions and Magenes (1972) for example.